# How do I determine what the nesting issue is when trying to combine multiple DynamicMaps in a layout

Tags: holoviews

I am using HoloViews version 1.12.0 .  I am attempting to create a layout that contains two DynamicMaps, but I am getting the error:

`WARNING:param.Warning: Layout contains HoloMaps which are not nested in the recommended format for accessing your data; calling .collate() on these objects will resolve any violations of the recommended nesting presented in the Composing Data tutorial ...`

One of the DynamicMaps itself contains a layout that consists of a Radial Heat Map, and a Div.  The other DynamicMap contains a Table object.  The idea is to add some additional DynamicMaps to the layout, such that there are streams creating click through parent child relationship between the DynamicMaps.

I have run the .collate() function on both of the DynamicMaps, but it didn't return any output, and the error persists.

If I alter the one DynamicMap that contains the layout of the div and radial heat map, to just containing the one object or the other, the issue goes away.

Here is the data structures output for my layout.

```
:Layout
   .DynamicMap.I  :DynamicMap   [ownership,survey_type,rep,approval,timeframe,nps_type]
   .DynamicMap.II :DynamicMap   [ownership,survey_type,rep,approval,timeframe,nps_type]
```

Answer (score 0):

The http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Building_Composite_Objects.html user guide explains the order things need to be nested to work smoothly without collate:

[image]

A DynamicMap normally takes the same spot as a HoloMap in such a hierarchy.

I'm surprised that .collate() "didn't return any output", though; I don't think there is any version of .collate() in HoloViews that doesn't return something, so there's presumably some other problem.

Comment: Thanks @james, I reviewed that documentation, but nothing seemed to indicate that my use of a layout containing two dynamic maps, where one of those dynamic maps itself contains a layout was incorrect.  Perhaps I am just not reading the diagram correctly.  I changed it to use 3 dynamic maps of simple elements, and the error went away.  I am also investigating the use of Panel for greater flexibility.